# Ajax dispara función de éxito sin ejecutar código php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, url

Tengo esta llamada ajax:

```
function GuardarPermisos(){
    var info = [];
    $("#table_Preparados > tbody > tr").each(function(){
    var permiso ={"evaluador" : $(this).find("td").eq(0).text(),"evaluado" : $(this).find("td").eq(1).text(),"relacion" : $(this).find("td").eq(2).text(),"fechaInicio" : $(this).find("td").eq(3).text(),"fechaFin" : $(this).find("td").eq(4).text(),"evaluacion" : $(this).find("td").eq(5).text(),"nivel" : $(this).find("td").eq(6).text(),"demografico" : $(this).find("td").eq(7).text()};
    info.push(permiso);
});

$.ajax({
  data:{"tableData": JSON.stringify(info)},
  url: "Model/permisos.php/Guardarpermiso",
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(datos) {
    alert("funciono");
  },
  error: function() {
    alert("error");
  }
});
```

El problema está en la llamada ajax que solicita la alerta "funciono", pero el código php no se ha ejecutado. De hecho, puedo proporcionar una ruta inexistente en la url y el código ajax también solicita la llamada de éxito.

Este es mi código php:

```
public function Guardarpermiso($tabla){


    // $lastIdPerm = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT id_permiso FROM `v2_permiso` ORDER BY `id_permiso` DESC LIMIT 1");
    // $lastIdPerm->execute();

    // $lastIdPerm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    // echo '<script languaje=’javascript’>alert("$lastId)</script>';


    // $lastIdPerm = $lastIdPerm + 1;

    $stm = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `v2_permiso`(`id_permiso`, `evaluado`, `evaluador`, `relacion`, `fecha_inicio`, `fecha_final`, `porcentaje`, `evaluacion`, `nivel`, `demografico`) VALUES ('31064','666','666','666','666','666','0','666','666','2')");
    $stm->execute();

    //Ejecución de la sentencia SQL.
    // $stm->execute(
    //     array(
    //         31064,
    //         666,
    //         666,
    //         666,
    //         666,
    //         666,
    //         666,
    //         666
    //     )
    // ); 
}
```

Lo comenté todo y solo dejé la inserción para descartar las opciones pero aún no funcionaba.

Comment: El poner el nombre del método en la URL no quiere decir que con eso se ejecute, para eso ocupas procesamiento extra, como mandar por `GET` el nombre del método y obtenerlo por PHP y ejecutarlo desde el archivo mismo

Comment: Utilizas algún framework o función de enrutado que procese correctamente la ruta `Model/permisos.php/Guardarpermiso` ?? Podrías mostrarnos el contenido de `permisos.php` ??

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Los callbacks `success` y `error` se ejecutan dependiendo del código HTTP recibido en la respuesta del servidor.

Por ejemplo:
Si el servidor responde con un código HTTP 200, entonces se ejecutará `success`.
Si el servidor responde con un código HTTP 401, entonces se ejecutará `error`.

Lo que tienes que hacer es, en el archivo que procesa la petición, generar la respuesta HTTP con el código correspondiente. Ejemplos, con php:

Respuesta para `success`:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
```

Respuesta para `error`:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 401 Not Authorized');
```

La API de Twitter es una buena referencia para determinar qué códigos utilizar y cuándo:

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/response-codes

Answer (score -1):

estoy revisando tu código y el problema esta aquí, estas haciendo mal el llamado de tu función 
No hagas esto

```js
 url: "Model/permisos.php/Guardarpermiso",
```

```js
 url: "Model/permisos.php",
```

Y ejecuta la funcion en el llamado, verifique que este en el directorio correcto tu .php

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta al problema del usuario. SI está mal, qué puede hacer para corregirlo? Por favor, revisa la sección [answer] para aprender más sobre cómo responder correctamente en [es.so]. Así mismo, te invito a realizar el [tour]